# Splits multidimensional array into sub array with same key value

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array with same key value uid.I want to 
convert this into sub array by  limiting foreach loop.you can see
two of uid has value 100 and two of uid has value 5465

```
$userdb=Array
(
    0 => Array
    (
        "uid"=> '100',
        "name" => 'Sandra Shush',
        "url"=> 'urlof100'
    ),

1 => Array
    (
        "uid"=> '5465',
        "name" => 'Sandra Shush',
        "url"=> 'urlof100'
    ),

2 => Array
    (
            "uid"=> '100',
        "name" => 'Sandra Shush',
        "url"=> 'urlof100'
    ),
3 => Array
    (
        "uid"=> '5465',
        "name" => 'Sandra Shush',
        "url"=> 'urlof100'
    ),

);
```

I want to get array like this.

```
$userdb=Array
(

  0 => Array(
      0 => Array
      (
          "uid"=> '100',
          "name" => 'Sandra Shush',
          "url"=> 'urlof100'
      ),
      2 => Array
      (
          "uid"=> '100',
          "name" => 'Sandra Shush',
          "url"=> 'urlof100'
      )
    ),
  1=> Array(
    1 => Array
    (
        "uid"=> '5465',
        "name" => 'Sandra Shush',
        "url"=> 'urlof100'
    ),
    3 => Array
    (
        "uid"=> '5465',
        "name" => 'Sandra Shush',
        "url"=> 'urlof100'
    )
  )
);
```

Can i get the result without using foreach loop ?

Comment: Without any for/foreach is impossible, but you can create a smaller loop that does not loop all values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without looping is impossible but you can limit your looping to just the unique uid's.

```
// Get all uids to an flat array
$uid = array_column($userdb, "uid");

// Loop the unique uids and find all matching uids and place them in array
foreach(array_unique($uid) as $id){
    $new[] = array_intersect_key($userdb, array_intersect($uid, [$id]));
}
var_dump($new);
```

This returns as your expected result.

https://3v4l.org/nWFVP

Comment: @Thanks for solution.Looks Better

Answer (score 2):

```
$userdb=[ ["uid"=> '100', "name" => 'Sandra Shush',"url"=> 'urlof100'],
["uid"=> '5465', "name" => 'Sandra Shush',"url"=> 'urlof100'],
["uid"=> '100', "name" => 'Sandra Shush',"url"=> 'urlof100'],
["uid"=> '5465', "name" => 'Sandra Shush',"url"=> 'urlof100']];

  foreach($userdb as $value) {
        $result[$value['uid']][] = $value;
  }

print_r(array_values($result));
```

Output:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [uid] => 100
                    [name] => Sandra Shush
                    [url] => urlof100
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [uid] => 100
                    [name] => Sandra Shush
                    [url] => urlof100
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [uid] => 5465
                    [name] => Sandra Shush
                    [url] => urlof100
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [uid] => 5465
                    [name] => Sandra Shush
                    [url] => urlof100
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: I don't want to use foreach loop.Any other method

Comment: @ShaanSetia that is impossible!

Comment: You are outputting an associative array, OP wants an indexed array. You should use array_values prior to your print_r